# The shark tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

The Stack Overflow [shark](/questions/tagged/shark) tag is being used for several very different things at the moment, and as such is almost useless. From its [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shark/info):

> Shark can refer to
>
> - Apple's performance analysis tool, "Shark" (currently part of "Instruments" application)
> - [S.Ha.R.K.](http://shark.sssup.it/) (Soft Hard Real-time Kernel) - real-time OS kernel
> - JIT compiler from OpenJDK's [Zero project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/zero/)
> - [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), a network protocol analyzer for capturing and interactively browsing traffic on computer networks.
> - Shark, a Hive-compatible large-scale data warehouse system based on Apache Spark.

Since the Apple performance tool [has been replaced by Instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556554/354577), and I was unable to find an Instruments tag, I suggest creating a new tag [apple-instruments](/questions/tagged/apple-instruments) for that use.

I also suggest discouraging the Wireshark use in favour of the existing [wireshark](/questions/tagged/wireshark) and [tshark](/questions/tagged/tshark) tags.

The "Hive-compatible large-scale data warehouse system based on Apache Spark" seems to be the most common use at the moment, and should likely become the official use of this tag.

I am open to suggestions about the remaining two uses ("Soft Hard Real-time Kernel" and "OpenJDK Zero JIT compiler").

Comment: The Apache thing could probably be renamed to something like [tag:shark-sql]... Leaving anything on this tag will only cause more confusion in the future.

Comment: Also, are there even actually questions about S.Ha.R.K? If not, ditch it. The website says it hasn't even been updated since 2008, and the Bugzilla site as well as the forums for it is gone. I doubt anyone else will be coming here to ask questions about that...

Comment: There are a number of old questions using [tag:shark] for the Apple performance analysis tool from when it still existed. Should these also be retagged with [tag:apple-instruments]?

Comment: I implemented your latest suggested edit which got rejected @Chris (not sure why it did - I checked the tag and there were no questions). You had forgotten to change the excerpt though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [shark](/questions/tagged/shark) tag is now only being used for legacy Apple Shark questions.

I removed the Wireshark use from the tag wiki since no questions were using that, and [ben is uǝq backwards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/179419/ben-is-ueq-backwards) removed the Soft Hard Real-time Kernel, which was similarly not being used.

I created a new tag [shark-sql](/questions/tagged/shark-sql) as suggested by [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson), added some basic wiki content, and retagged all relevant uses.

I created a new tag [shark-compiler](/questions/tagged/shark-compiler), as [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221258/248627) by [Ian Kemp](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/189401/ian-kemp), added some basic wiki content, and retagged the only relevant question that I was able to find. This tag may not survive the test of time.

It turns out that there is an existing [xcode-instruments](/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments) tag that can be used for new Apple Instruments questions.

Finally, I updated the [shark](/questions/tagged/shark) wiki, discouraging its use for new questions, and pointing users to suggested alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

Apple's performance analysis tool => apple-shark
S.Ha.R.K. => shark-os (although wouldn't that be more on topic for Super User?)
JIT compiler from OpenJDK => shark-compiler
Wireshark => wireshark
Hive-compatible large-scale data warehouse system based on Apache Spark => shark

Comment: The Apple performance tool isn't called Shark any more. It is called Instruments. Since [tag:instruments] would be ambiguous I think [tag:apple-instruments] would be the appropriate tag to create instead.

Comment: I also don't think that Apache Shark should use the "shark" tag. If it's ambiguous then it's should be avoided.

Comment: I like "shark-compiler" for OpenJDK.